# Puppet : How to load file from agent

Tags: puppet

I have written a manifest that performs a number of tasks. The very first task is that it loads the contents of a file into a variable. The file will exist on the target node ( or managed node or the one running the Puppet agent).

However, when I triggered the manifest via a puppet run, I realized that it was expecting to find the file on the master, not the agent!

```
$some_var = file("path_to_file")
```

How do I fix this so that it loads the file from the agent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed functions execute only on the master. Therefore, you need either an external or custom fact for this to execute on the node. Here is a custom fact ready to go for this purpose of returning the contents of a file `foo`:

```
# module_name/lib/facter/foo_content.rb
Facter.add(:foo_content) do
  setcode do
    # return content of foo as a string
    File.read('/path/to/foo')
  end
end
```

You can then use this thusly:

```
# facter 3
$some_var = $facts['foo_content']
# facter 2
$some_var = $::foo_content
```

Note this solution assumes `foo` is not some extremely enormous file.

https://docs.puppet.com/facter/3.6/custom_facts.html

Comment: I read about this and it definitely appears to be extremely complicated. Its really odd that there is no way to perform such a simple task in Puppet. Can the ruby file reside under my module or does it have to be in a custom location on the Puppet master ? I tried it within my module but it did not work.

Comment: It isn't actually complicated at all. Note my code above performs what you need in only a few lines. The preferred location for the custom fact file is inside the `lib/facter` directory inside the module you are using it in (as I suggest above), so pluginsync copies it over whenever that module is part of the directory environment and it becomes available always and only when necessary.

Comment: When I do a puppet run, it displays the contents of the file to the screen, so I know its doing something. But the "fact" does not contain the contents of the file. Not sure why.

Comment: You need to remove the puts, otherwise it won't take the content.

Comment: @PeterSouter Completely correct. I didn't have complete confidence that I was doing the implied type for the Ruby return correctly, and I can't blame interpreted language idiosyncrasies for this one since C++ behaves the same way. I should have known better that `ostream != string`.

Comment: Yep, Ruby is weird sometimes. It'll return whatever it finds last, so with the puts, it returns a nil as a method, so the fact would return nil.

I would also warn that depending on the size of this file, this could cause bloat in PuppetDB or in catalogs kept on disk or in logging.

Comment: @PeterSouter Yeah I mentioned that "this solution assumes foo is not some extremely enormous file", but didn't really get into the kind of consequences to system memory that could result. Forgot about the logging file part too.

Comment: @Peter, that was it ! Removing the "puts" did the trick. One major annoyance is that every time I execute puppet agent ( whether its related to this class or not ), it executes that "fact" and prints the contents of that file to the screen.

Comment: @user It shouldn't do that after removing the `puts`. Is it occurring during pluginsync?